# Python combinations between 3 lists with one depending on one list

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

I have two lists and a third list that depends on the first one (if l1 is 1, then the element to take in l3 is 11 or 111, if l2 is 2, then l3 to take is 22, or 222).

```
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = [3, 4]

l3 = [[11, 111], [22, 222]] # the numbers are calculated for each element of l1
```

What I would like is to create a combination resulting in:

```
[(1,3,11), (1,3,111), (1,4,11), (1,4,111), (2,3,22), (2,3,222), (2,4,22), (2,4,222)]
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: We don't know how the third depends on the first of you don't tell us.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks all! In the end, I ended up with this:

```
combo = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        for k in range(len(l3[i])):
            combo.append((l1[i], l2[j], l3[i][k]))
            
combo
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
tuples = []
for l1_index, a in enumerate(l1):
    for b in l2:
         for c in l3[l1_index]:
             tuples.append((a,b,c))
print(tuples)

>>> [(1, 3, 11), (1, 3, 111), (1, 4, 11), (1, 4, 111), (2, 3, 22), (2, 3, 222), (2, 4, 22), (2, 4, 222)]
```

Comment: Try `for a, cs in zip(l1, l3):`

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between l1 and l3 isn't clear but assuming it's merely positional, you could use a nested comprehension with zip() to combine l1 and l3:

```
[ (a,b,c) for a,ac in zip(l1,l3) for b in l2 for c in ac  ]

[(1, 3, 11), (1, 3, 111), (1, 4, 11), (1, 4, 111), (2, 3, 22), 
 (2, 3, 222), (2, 4, 22), (2, 4, 222)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```py
import itertools                                                                     

combo = list(itertools.chain(*[                                                          
    itertools.product([l1[i]], l2, l3[i])                                            
    for i in range(len(l1))                                                          
]))
```

This loops over `l1`, and for each `i`th element it produces all combinations with this element followed by any one of `l2` and any one of the `i`th list in `l3`.

The `itertools.chain` call to combine all lists of combinations could also be rewritten as a list comprehension:

```py
combo3 = [
    e
    for i in range(len(l1))
    for e in itertools.product([l1[i]], l2, l3[i])
]
```

---

A quick benchmark with all lists of length 100, `len(l3[i]) == 5`, and 1000 iterations ([code](https://gist.github.com/bfontaine/62256c233e7d8f5717392357aa94283e)):

- [Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925687/735926): 4.92s
- With `itertools.chain`: 1.95s
- With a list comprehension: 2.13s

Comment: Seems odd to use itertools but avoid zip...

Comment: And just another way, getting rid of all Python iteration by using map: `list(itertools.chain(*map(
        itertools.product,
        zip(l1),
        itertools.repeat(l2),
        l3
    )))`. Or: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(
        itertools.product,
        zip(l1),
        itertools.repeat(l2),
        l3
    )))`

Comment: @KellyBundy `itertools` is mandatory to get the product, but `zip` is not.

Comment: But it's still odd to use a heavy imported tool and not use a smaller built-in tool, instead using unpythonic indexed looping. Wait, do you think I meant the zip in my later alternative way? I didn't. I meant it for the parallel iteration of l1 and l3, as I had also suggested under C. McCracken's answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy Actually, I find McCracken’s answer easier to read _without_ `zip` rather than with it, but I guess that with correct naming (and not just `a`/`b`/`c`) it would be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt:

```
def combine_lists(l1, l2, l3):
    result = []
    for index, i in enumerate(l1):
        for j in l2:
            result.append((i, j, l3[index][0]))
            result.append((i, j, l3[index][1]))
    return result
```

Running the following produces the outcome you described:

```
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = [3, 4]
l3 = [[11, 111], [22, 222]]

combination = combine_lists(l1, l2, l3)
print(combination)
```